# Sorting an creates a problem in user defined function

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a code to check whether a given poset is a lattice or not. For that I am using a map container `map<int,list<int> >`. The following insertion function works well if the array is not sorted using any sort function (both user defined and in-built STL sort function). Could anyone tell as to where I am going wrong?

```
void insertion(map<int, list<int> > m, int* arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        pair<int, list<int> > p;
        list<int> l;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] % arr[j] == 0)
                l.push_back(arr[j]);
        }
        p = make_pair(arr[i], l);
        m.insert(p);
    }
    for (map<int, list<int> >::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first << "->";
        for (list<int>::iterator jt = it->second.begin(); jt != it->second.end(); ++jt)
            cout << *jt << ",";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    map<int, list<int> > m;
    int arr[] = { 45, 9, 15, 3, 5, 1 };
    cout << "Checking if lattice for divisibility relation on given set" << endl << "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << ",";
    cout << "}\n";
    sort(arr,arr+6);
    insertion(m, arr);
}
```

Comment: In general, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, you're not even describing a problem. Also, extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question, along with error messages or output you get and output that you would expect instead.

Comment: `insertion` takes your `map` by value, so the variable in `main` is never updated.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. I'll be sure to keep that in mind @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: But I have displayed the contents of the map in the `insert` function itself. The list is displayed just fine if I don't sort the array beforehand. The base address of `arr` is sent as an argument. So why does it not display the output after all I did is sort the array? @StephenNewell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you're deciding what gets added to your `list`s.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    pair<int, list<int> > p;
    list<int> l;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 6; ++j) {
        if (arr[i] % arr[j] == 0)
            l.push_back(arr[j]);
    }
    p = make_pair(arr[i], l);
    m.insert(p);
}
```

When `arr` is sorted, `arr[i]` will always be less than or equal to `arr[j]`.  This means that unless they're equal (and based on your input, they won't be), your `if` will never be true.  For example, `1%5` (the first check that's performed) will be 1.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Thank you!